# Concatenation of date time with a string in php

Tags: php

I am trying to attach data and time with a filename but it is not working without any errors:

```
$date = date('Y/m/d H:i:s');
$pdf = $date.'order_sheet.pdf';
```

Through this code the file didn't become downloaded

Comment: what do you mean by `attach`? attaching to email? Or sending out to clients using `Content-disposition`? Or?

Comment: All you do is assign variables. What is the reason you expect this making a file downloadable?

Comment: Attach mean Concatenation with file name like pdf

Comment: also its not a good filename. Try something like `date('Y_m_d_H_i_s');`

Comment: ^^^ what they said + plus I would suggest more friendly filenames such as `date('Y-m-d-His') . '-order-sheet.pdf';`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using slashes and whitespaces in the filename, this isn't a good idea. Try to replace them with some other char, like so:

```
$date = date('Y_m_d-H-i-s');
```

Answer (score 0):

this will have special characters and space in the file name which is not allowed.
That may be the cause.
you should use timestamp instead of date & time.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use a / in a filename